# Securing POST request

Tags: node.js, security, express

I have a expresjs application

How can I secure the ID when POSTing a form.

I had a hidden field id in the form:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" hidden="hidden" value="1">
```

The id can be easily changed to POST a invalid data to my database.

How can I secure it? should I hash it?

Comment: My first thought was to hash the "id" in concert with a secret salt. Or "sign" the ID value using a public key of some sort. You'd store the hashed/signed value as another hidden form element.

Comment: Or just validate the data server side, e.g. some code that ensures the passed ID corresponds to the current user.

Comment: What are your _concerns_ when you think of securing the ID? From the context you've provided so far, I'd say you should authenticate the request either by padding authentication data or establishing a session which has been authenticated first. Since you'd probably use the ID to update, delete or create data related to that ID, you should check if the ID _belogs_ or _is accessible_ by the requester. Further, you might harden the request against [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to encrypt the value using a reversible encryption method (hashing won't work since it is irreversible). Then when you receive the encrypted ID back at the server, decrypt it to get the value.

However, I wouldn't suggest doing that, no point for such a hassle just to prevent someone from changing the ID on postback. There may be tens of other fields in your form, how can you possibly secure all of them?

I suggest you do proper validation when you receive the postback data, for example:

> If `User A` is trying to edit his `Profile ID 1234`, the form will have a hidden field of `ID 1234`, when the user completes the edit operation and post the data back to the server, validate that `User A` has the rights to edit the posted `Profile ID`, if he has the right to do so, it doesn't matter if he change the ID to something else other than the original value.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to solve a wrong problem.  All the POST data should be checked on the server side for consistency.